# kubernetes: waiting for first consumer to be created before binding

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to run kafka/zookeeper on Kubernetes. Using helm charts I am able to install zookeeper on the cluster. However the ZK pods are stuck in pending state. When I issued describe on one of the pod "`didn't find available persistent volumes to bind, 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.`" was the reason for scheduling failure. But when I issue describe on PVC ,  I am getting "`waiting for first consumer to be created before binding`". I tried to re-spawn the whole cluster but the result is same. Trying to use https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/ as guide.

Can someone please guide me here ?

**kubectl get pods -n zoo-keeper**

```
kubectl get pods -n zoo-keeper
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
zoo-keeper-zk-0              0/1     Pending   0          20m
zoo-keeper-zk-1              0/1     Pending   0          20m
zoo-keeper-zk-2             0/1     Pending   0          20m
```

**kubectl get sc**

```
kubectl get sc
NAME            PROVISIONER                    AGE
local-storage   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   25m
```

**kubectl describe  sc**

```
kubectl describe  sc
Name:            local-storage
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"local-storage"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/no-provisioner","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}

Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
Parameters:            <none>
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
Events:                <none>
```

**kubectl describe pod foob-zookeeper-0 -n zoo-keeper**

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl describe pod foob-zookeeper-0 -n zoo-keeper
Name:               foob-zookeeper-0
Namespace:          zoo-keeper
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             app=foob-zookeeper
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance=data-coord
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Tiller
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=foob-zookeeper
                    app.kubernetes.io/version=foob-zookeeper-9.1.0-15
                    controller-revision-hash=foob-zookeeper-5321f8ff5
                    release=data-coord
                    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=foob-zookeeper-0
Annotations:        foobar.com/product-name: zoo-keeper ZK
                    foobar.com/product-revision: ABC
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      StatefulSet/foob-zookeeper
Containers:
  foob-zookeeper:
    Image:       repo.data.foobar.se/latest/zookeeper-3.4.10:1.6.0-15
    Ports:       2181/TCP, 2888/TCP, 3888/TCP, 10007/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  4Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      1
      memory:   2Gi
    Liveness:   exec [zkOk.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  tcp-socket :2181 delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      ZK_REPLICAS:           3
      ZK_HEAP_SIZE:          1G
      ZK_TICK_TIME:          2000
      ZK_INIT_LIMIT:         10
      ZK_SYNC_LIMIT:         5
      ZK_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS:   60
      ZK_SNAP_RETAIN_COUNT:  3
      ZK_PURGE_INTERVAL:     1
      ZK_LOG_LEVEL:          INFO
      ZK_CLIENT_PORT:        2181
      ZK_SERVER_PORT:        2888
      ZK_ELECTION_PORT:      3888
      JMXPORT:               10007
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/zookeeper from datadir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nfcfx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-foob-zookeeper-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-nfcfx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nfcfx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  69s (x4 over 3m50s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind, 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

**kubectl get  pv**

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get  pv
NAME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
local-pv   50Gi       RWO            Retain           Available           local-storage            10m
ubuntu@kmaster:~$
```

**kubectl get  pvc local-claim**

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get  pvc local-claim
NAME          STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
local-claim   Pending                                      local-storage   8m9s
ubuntu@kmaster:~$
```

**kubectl describe pvc local-claim**

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl describe pvc local-claim
Name:          local-claim
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason                Age                    From                         Message
  ----       ------                ----                   ----                         -------
  Normal     WaitForFirstConsumer  2m3s (x26 over 7m51s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
Mounted By:  <none>
```

**MY PV files:**

**cat create-pv.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/kafka-mount
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kmaster
```

**cat pvc.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you created your PV on master node. By default master node is marked unschedulable by ordinary pods using so called taint. To be able to run some service on master node you have two options:

1) Add toleration to some service to allow it to run on master node:

```
tolerations:
- effect: NoSchedule
  key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

You may even specify that some service runs only on master node:

```
nodeSelector:
  node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
```

2) You can remove taint from master node, so any pod can run on it. You should know that this is dangerous because can make your cluster very unstable.

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Read more here and taints and tolerations: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/